# Are there any known common causes of "Cannot kill process: Success!" in error.log?

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, centos7

Operating system: CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)

Error log: /var/log/httpd/error.log

Apache version: Apache/2.4.6

In attempting to debug a PHP cron task, I am seeing some segfaults in error.log around the times it is attempting to execute. Each segfault recording is preceded on the line above with the a "cannot kill process" error for a different process ID (for example):

```
Sun Apr 14 18:18:27 2019 (1893): Error Cannot kill process 1169: Success!
[Sun Apr 14 18:18:27.170950 2019] [core:notice] [pid 6755] AH00052: child pid 1893 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

The process ID (and obviously, the time stamp) on the top line are different for each instance. It is never the same as the pid or child pid in the second line.

I haven't found any information on this error message. It is not an easy one to search for.

The basic process is that I have some PHP (7.1.27) cron tasks running in Drupal 8.6.12, and crontab uses wget on the Drupal site's cron URL to make it check if any are behind schedule, and runs any that are. There is a weekly task (which runs some very slow MySQL queries) that seems as if it's failing because httpd is stopping entirely partway through the task (I'm not sure if this is actually the case or not, but the evidence I have points to this), meaning Drupal therefore cannot record a success or a failure, and on the next crontab run it tries to run it again, believing it to not have run yet. I believe this is what these segfaults are telling me, but I can't make heads or tails of the "Success!" error message. I'm not sure what this error is even reporting to be able to debug further.

Edit: Additional info from httpd -l:

```
Compiled in modules:
core.c
mod_so.c
http_core.c
```

Info from httpd -V:

```
Server MPM:     prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
```

edit: changed my config to use php-fpm and event MPM, but unfortunately the cron task is still crashing, and now I'm seeing "zend_mm_heap corrupted" instead of segfaults. But I guess the segfault error technically went away.

Comment: Hmm. You might be running into [this PHP bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76482), or a related bug. You can workaround it by using php-fpm and the event MPM. Of course you should be doing that anyway for the significantly improved performance.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thank you very much - I'll admit this is a little outside of my expertise. Are there any other implications I should be aware of or address in making these changes? I'm primarily a PHP developer with limited sysadmin experience.

Comment: Nothing major. It's just reconfiguring Apache and PHP and there are plenty of tutorials on how to do that.

Comment: Unfortunately the cron task is still crashing, and now I'm seeing "zend_mm_heap corrupted" instead of segfaults. But I guess the segfault error technically went away.

Comment: Probably a different bug, then. But almost certainly some kind of bug.